# Create a category column in pandas based on string content in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to tag Pandas rows based on their values in a string column.
The desired output is this:

[image]

I have this code:

```
data = [{'age': 44, 'time': 150, 'name': "ape monkey"},
         {'age': 55,  'time': 200, 'name': "pig monkey"},
         {'age': 66,  'time': 50,  'name': "ape cow"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

apes = df['name'].str.contains("ape")
monkeys = df['name'].str.contains("monkey")
```

What would be a good way to create the column `type` as in the desired output above?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an unconventional solution using `map`:

```
(2*apes + monkeys).map({0: 'neither', 1: 'monkey', 2: 'ape', 3: 'both'})

0      both
1    monkey
2       ape
Name: name, dtype: object
```

The idea is to assign apes a value of 2 and monkeys a value of 1, then sum the two and look at the result.